# Why is Linq2DB executing SQL-Statement after disposing DataContext

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, deferred-execution, linq2db

I have tested the following code with Linq2DB:

```
IQueryable<M> entities = null;

using (var context = new DataContext("MySql", ConnectionString))  
{
    entities = context.GetTable<M>();
}

var list = entities.ToList();

return entities;
```

I wonder why the query at `entities.ToList()` is executed even though the `DataContext` was disposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `DataContext` is designed (compared to `DataConnection` context implementation). By default it acquires connection only for single query (or transaction, if you use it), and releases it back to pool after query executed/transaction completed/disposed, so it is safe.

Another situation will be if you will set `KeepConnectionAlive` to `true`. I suspect in this case we will have connection leak, so I will fill issue for it.

Answer (score 1):

The `entities` variable just contains a reference to the table. You should materialize your data in scope of the context, so you could do smth like

```
IQueryable<M> entities = null;
List<M> realEntities = null;

using (var context = new DataContext("MySql", ConnectionString))  
{
    entities = context.GetTable<M>();

    // materialize entities in scope of the context
    realEntities = entities.ToList();
}

return realEntities;
```

Also you could perform some filtering before the materialization:

```
using (var context = new DataContext("MySql", ConnectionString))  
{
    entities = context.GetTable<M>();

    // you can apply Where filter here, it won't trigger the materialization.
    entities = entities.Where(e => e.Quantity > 50);

    // what exactly happens there: 
    // 1. Data from the M table is filtered
    // 2. The filtered data only is retrieved from the database
    //    and stored in the realEntities variable (materialized).
    realEntities = entities.ToList();
}
```

There is a [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/intermediate-materialization) about materialization I recommend you to look into.

Comment: I know this. I wonder, why can I do the materialization AFTER disposing the context? I think there should be no connection etc. after disposing the context - or am I wrong?